# OpenAPI Specification (YML/YAML) : All $refs replace or expand to its definition (with schema validation)

Tags: java, python, yaml, openapi

I am looking for some solution or maybe some script that can help me to replace($ref) or expand its definitions within the YML file with schema validation. (For detail please find below example)

**Example: Input with $ref **

```
  /pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: showPetById
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the pet to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Expected response to a valid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - name
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
    Pets:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
    Error:
      type: object
      required:
        - code
        - message
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        message:
          type: string
```

**Output: All $ref replace or expanded to its definition (with schema validation)**

```
  /pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: showPetById
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the pet to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Expected response to a valid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                required:
                  - id
                  - name
                properties:
                  id:
                    type: integer
                    format: int64
                  name:
                    type: string
                  tag:
                    type: string

        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                required:
                  - code
                  - message
                properties:
                  code:
                    type: integer
                    format: int32
                  message:
                    type: string
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - name
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
    Pets:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        required:
          - id
          - name
        properties:
          id:
            type: integer
            format: int64
          name:
            type: string
          tag:
            type: string

    Error:
      type: object
      required:
        - code
        - message
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        message:
          type: string
```

Can you please suggest?

Comment: OpenAPI requires `$ref` values to be something like `#/Tag` for referencing items in the same document, your example uses invalid syntax. The expected output you give contradicts what you describe, since you say all `$ref`s should be replaced but `$ref: Tag` is still part of the output. That said, does [prance](https://pypi.org/project/prance/) help you?

Comment: @flyx : fyi, updated the sample. Any idea of how I can utilize the prance to achieve $ref s to be replaced with all the definitions.

Comment: I don't know the tool but from the docs `prance compile my_file.yml output.yml` should do it

Comment: @flyx - thanks for posting, it looks like it might be helpful.

Comment: Just curios - why do you need this? Most if not all OpenAPI tools (doc tools, codegens, etc.) can handle internal $refs just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some tools that can claim to be able dereference internal $refs in addition to external ones. Be aware of potential issues with circular $refs.

CLI:

- https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-cli

  ```
  swagger-cli bundle --dereference <file>
  ```
- [Redocly OpenAPI CLI](https://redoc.ly/docs/cli/commands/#how-to-make-a-fully-dereferenced-bundle)

  ```
  openapi bundle --dereferenced --output <outputName> --ext <ext> [entrypoints...]
  ```

Libraries:

- Java: [Swagger Parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser) with the [`resolvefully`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser#2-resolvefully) option
- Node.js: [oas-resolver](https://github.com/Mermade/oas-kit/tree/master/packages/oas-resolver) with the [`resolveInternal`](https://github.com/Mermade/oas-kit/blob/master/docs/options.md) option

Comment: swagger-cli has been deprecated and they recommend using [Redocly OpenAPI CLI](https://redocly.com/redocly-cli/).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the OpenAPI/Swagger editor at https://editor-next.swagger.io/. Load the definition file then select "File" -> "Download Resolved YAML"

Comment: Prefer a web solution, so thanks!