# Inline $refs from OpenAPI when importing to Postman

Tags: postman, openapi

I imported an OpenAPI definition to Postman, and it works beautifully, but I have declared error responses as refs. And unfortunately Postman doesn't see that as in JSON, it sees only $ref like that:

```json
"200": {
    "description": "Message confirmed",
    "content": {
        "application/json": {
            "schema": {
                "required": [
                    "success"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "success": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "example": true
                    }
                },
                "type": "object"
            }
        }
    }
},
"400": {
    "$ref": "#/components/responses/RequestValidationFailedResponse"
},
```

As you can imagine, 200 is visible fully and 400 status doesn't name the example as in the description (inside the $ref). Can I do something while importing to Postman? Or inline the variables?

Comment: Looks like a bug/limitation of Postman. I suggest you report this to Postman support. As a workaround, you can pre-process your definition using a [$ref resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65691276/113116) before importing it into Postman.